# Memory allocation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning Spark and trying to understand, for example, why iSpark doing following things:

I have 3 main things I'm doing in Spark, one after another, lets call them Processors. All of them are not dependent on each other. 
1. Open .csv file, perform some processing and calculations, like group by, find mean, median etc.(ProcessorOne)
2. Open another .csv file, perform different processing.(ProcessorTwo)
3. Open third file , perform another calculations.(ProcessorThree)

I expected from Spark, that it will start  ProcessorTwo, after finishing first one.
But in logs output I see statements from part 3, part 2, part 1 **mixed up.**
For Example I can see that it's submitting task in ProcessorThree, but I haven't seen results from ProcessorOne yet.

```
18/04/17 15:03:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 31 missing tasks from Stage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[17] at mapToPair at ProcessorThree.java:99)
```

Initially, I thought, that It should finish ProcessorOne first.

I thought, that It will allocate memory to read file in ProcessorTwo after finishing with ProcessorOne and memory will be released.  Does it means that it allocating memory to all processors first?
**Why its important to me:** when I run my app on small dataset - it's fine. But when I increase amount of data each of my processor using, its starting to slow down and taking forever to finish my app.

Comment: How and when are you collecting/writing the data from each Process? Spark is lazy and will only evaluate when needed.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I am running all these 3 classes with Processors in a loop. Each processor has processData(). This method returns JavaPairRDD<String, String>. Before loop, I am specifying result variable. For each processor, I am joining result of each processData() method with result variable, that will hold results of all 3 processors. When 3 iterations of loop is done, I am saving to file result variable, that now contains of results of all 3 processors. Note, that while input data is quite large, result of each processor is just a few lines. How can I make Spark process one processor after another?